# aggregate query taking long time. How we can improve performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are fetching data from applicant and ticket collection. applicant collection has 19000 records and ticket collection has 10000 records.
Please suggest how to improve the performance of the below query. Thanks in advance.

```
 totalData = await applicantObj.aggregate([
        {
            $match: findApplicantCriteria
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'tickets',
                let: { applicant_id: '$_id' },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr:
                                findCriteria
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: 'tickets'
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                id: "$_id",
                name: "$F_First_name",
                phoneNumber: "$F_R_Mobile_no",
                email: "$F_Email_id",
                crn: "$Reg_No",
                generatedTickets: { $size: "$tickets" },
            }
        },
        {
            $match: { generatedTickets: { "$gt": 0 } }
        },
        {
            $count: "total"
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Have a look at the [execution plan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#std-label-example-aggregate-method-explain-option). Add `{explain: true}` to your aggregation pipeline.

Comment: for the lookup with pipeline with $expr to use index you need >= Mongodb 5, create also indexes on fileds that you are using on findCreateria